# Mapping an array inside an array with a JSON Reader

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

My JSON looks as follows:

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "_id": "5106f97bdcb713b818d7f1f1",
            "cn": "lsacco",
            "favorites": [
                {
                    "fullName": "Friend One",
                    "uid": "friend1"
                },
                {
                    "fullName": "Friend Two",
                    "uid": "friend2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to use records.favorites as the root for my JSON reader, I do not get any results populated to my model.  Is there a way to do this without having to resort to using an association? Note that in my case, records will only have one element despite it showing an array.

Comment: So your model corresponds to the records within `favorites`? Why have `records` as the top level in your json?

Comment: It's to have consistency in the model when there is the case for multiples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`records.favorites` isn't valid because the property doesn't exist.

You want:

`records[0].favorites`

Answer (score 0):

***records*** has been declared as an array so ***records.favorites*** will point to nothing in the json data file.

using the index in records should solve the problem.